# Loses Auth :: user () when declaring an Oberserver in AppServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use a local scope in one of my models but for this I need to check the user permission, so I try to get the autenticated user by Auth::user().

But it givens me a null because I have an Observer declared for this model, and if I comment the declaration of the Observer the Auth::user() method give me a user authenticated.

There is a correct way or place to declare the Observer and in the model I can get the authenticated user, because I need to use Observers and get in boot method the authenticated user?

Laravel Framework 6.5.2

AppServiceProvider Don't work auth in model

```
 /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Conciliador::observe(ConciliadorObserver::class);
        Proposta::observe(PropostaObserver::class);

    }
```

AppServiceProvider work auth in model

```
 /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //Conciliador::observe(ConciliadorObserver::class);
        //Proposta::observe(PropostaObserver::class);

    }
```

Model does not have user logged in when Observer is declared in AppServiceProvider

```
 /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        $user = Auth::user();
        dd($user); // null if Observer is declared in AppServiceProvider
        if($user && $user->tipo == 'admin-gerenciador'){
            $conciliadores = $user->conciliadores->pluck('id')->toArray();
            static::addGlobalScope('Conciliadores', function (Builder $builder) {
                $builder->whereIn('id',$conciliadores);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 6.5.2 @ChinLeung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't call `Auth::user()` anywhere. It may trigger authentication side-effects. It is highly recommended to do that only in controllers and middleware.
- But you can safely call `Auth::user()` if you check by **`Auth::hasUser()`** in advance; it checks if the user is ALREADY authenticated.

So your code goes like:

```
/**
 * The "booting" method of the model.
 */
protected static function boot(): void
{
    static::addGlobalScope('Conciliadores', function (Builder $query) {
        if (Auth::hasUser() && Auth::user()->tipo === 'admin-gerenciador') {
            $query->whereKey(Auth::user()->conciliadores->modelKeys());
        }
    });
}
```

It's very simple solution. Even middleware is unnecessary.

#### EDIT

This scope is **always available**, but actually **apply conditions only if the user is already authenticated**.

Comment: Thankyou @mpyw, but I need to apply the scope to the model after the codes passes by boot method on the AppServiceProvider and has the logged user. How do I do that?

Comment: Would you prefer "the global scope for every user only applied after authentication" than "the global scope only for authenticated user always applied"? I think they behave exactly the same way, but dare you choose the complex implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing this in your model's boot method like that. The `boot` method is only called **once** for the model, not for every model instance. The first time the model is used `boot` gets called, which would be when you are adding the observer for it in the Service Provider in your case; which would be way before the request is dispatched to a route and through the middleware stack. (There is no session at this point, so no authenticated user.)

You probably want to add your global scope to your model via a middleware.

Comment: Could you please give me a example how to do that using middleware? @lagbox